# Can the POJO corresponding to JSON structure be null in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using jackson-annotations 2.4 and related jars to covert from JSON to POJO. Let's say I have a structure as follows in my json:

```
person
{
  name 
 {
   firstName,
   lastName
  }
}
```

I have POJO for the person defined as:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"name"})
class Person
{
  private Name name;

  @JsonProperty("name")
  public Name getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  @JsonProperty("name")
  public void setName(Name name)
  {
     this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Assume I've a similar POJO defined for Name. Now my question is can the getter for `Name` in `Person` ever return a null value or it gets instantiated behind the scenes?

I tried searching on google but it seemed like jackson returned default values for the non-nullable fields but there was no mention about what happens to the structure?

Comment: You can just try it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the json you use to parse, i.e:

```
{
    "name": {
        "firstname": "abc",
        "lastname": "xyz"
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "name": {
    }
}
```

Both JSONs above will never return null for `person.getName()`, even if the fields inside the node are missing. But on the other hand if you don't pass the node `name` on your json, then `person.getName()` will always return null. For instance, this JSON will always cause `person.getName()` to be null:

```
{
    "name": "abc"
}
```

Comment: Ah so it depends on the service/api which is populating the json?

Comment: I can't answer for other frameworks, but Jackson unless there are some obscure annotation I don't know about, will always depend on the nodes you have on your JSON. By nodes I am the objects inside each JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . This will definitely work out. I was facing same got the solution by this.

```
  @JsonInclude(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

or

```
 @JsonInclude( JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
```

you may also try by Remove this

```
 @JsonPropertyOrder({"name"}) //remove this
```